# How to create custom dropdownsearch in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement dropdownsearch functionality in my project but it is only accepting list of type String. I am fetching data using API and hence a list of the type object models. How can I use custom dropdownsearch so that it accepts my model type list?
OR Is there any way to convert List of type Object Model to List of type string in flutter?
Anyone solution will be acceptable, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asked this an hour ago. don't make new accounts just to post the same kind of question. Even worse, this doesn't include any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can map your object from API and display them as String.
You could do something like this:

```
class CustomObject {
  final String name;
  final double data;

  CustomObject(this.name, this.data);
}

...
{
  final dataFromApi = [
    CustomObject('first', 20.0),
    CustomObject('second', 20.0),
  ];

  final mappedData = dataFromApi.map((element) => element.name).toList();

  // ['first', 'second']
}
...
```

Then you only need to find a way to compare clicked dropdown value with your api data list and determine, which object to select.

e.g:

```
  final obj = dataFromApi.firstWhere((element) => element.name == selectedString);
```